# Dose curl_exec does usual http request as browser?

Tags: php, http, curl, browser

I want to know if the curl_exec function does the same request as a browser?

Can you know who sends a request is using browser or some code like php?

Is there any difference among these two methods and is it recognizable by the server?

I mean that curl to an url by any programming language or any other way has same request and result?

Comment: What is a curl request?  If you can define that, you have your answer.  The only way the server can know is to look at the headers sent with the request.  It has no way of knowing if the requester is being truthful, though.

Comment: If you want to know about legitimate responsible scrapers there are a some good questions and answers already in [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677419/how-to-detect-search-engine-bots-with-php) [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544450/detecting-honest-web-crawlers) and [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667734/malicious-crawler-blocker-for-asp-net), if you want to know about malicious bots [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161548/how-do-i-prevent-site-scraping/34828465#34828465) has some good answers.